# Running gvim from MSYS --- how to avoid/change MSYS enviroment variables?

Tags: vim, environment-variables, sh, msys

When I run `gvim` from MSYS, things go wrong during initialization.  Namely, `gvim` can't find the initialization files that are in '`C:\Documents and Settings\username\vimfiles`.

[Specifically, gvim reports the error `E117: Unknown function: pathogen#infect` during initialization, so it never found `autoload\pathogen.vim`.  Doing `:scriptnames` also confirms that none of the setup files from `vimfiles\` are run.]

I think I've debugged why it goes wrong.  When you start MSYS, the MSYS shell inherits the windows enviroment variables, but changes some of them to it's custom values.  `C:\Documents and Settings\username` is the value of `$HOME` in Windows, but MSYS sets it to something like `C:/msys/user name`.  And of course, Vim uses `$HOME` to find the right initialization files.

I also notice `set shell?` has changed to something like `shell=C:/msys/bin/sh` instead of `shell=C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe`, but I hope this isn't important for fixing the initialization problem.

I need to run gvim with the normal windows environment variables.  At least I need to be able to manually override a few important ones like `$HOME` to something I specify (i.e., I'm not concerned about my windows `$HOME` changing, so it's fine to use a static value).

I tried to reset `$HOME` manually in my vimrc, but by then it is too late.

Is there some trick to specifying `$HOME` early on during initialization, or as an extra command line parameter?

Alternatively, is there some trick with running commands from `msys` differently?  I know almost nothing about how the shell `C:/msys/bin/sh` works, but I could conceive of some extra arguments that changes the visibile environment for the command (e.g. `gvim.exe`) you are typing.

**---Edit---**
Reposting the solution that worked (it achieves the later idea):

Instead of running `gvim.exe`, run the command `HOME="C:\Documents and Settings\username" gvim.exe`

Comment: Did you try changing the value of `$HOME` in what `msys` uses as configuration file? Something like `export $HOME="C:\Documents and Settings\username"`.

Comment: Yes, gvim will work from msys if `HOME` is set properly in advance.  (The syntax is `export HOME="C:\Documents and Settings\username"` though, without the '$').  But like I said I need a way so that `gvim.exe` will see the right value of `HOME` without changing `HOME` globally for the shell.  Is there a way to `export` only for a single command?

Comment: My knowledge of the Windows command line is *very* close to `0` but in `*sh` I can do `$ HOME='/path/to/dir' vim filename`. Be careful with that method, though, because `$HOME` is set to a different location than the default one Vim won't see your `_vimrc` or your `vimfiles` unless you place them in that new `$HOME`. Also, using `msys`-provided commands may be harder or even impossible because of that new `$HOME`. I'd say "duplicate your files or use symlinks".

Comment: The first suggestion does the trick.  gvim sees the Windows value of `HOME`, and not msys's `HOME`, but when I return to the shell the msys HOME hasn't been changed.    If you repost it as an answer I will accept it.  The suggestion to abandon my windows vim setup is exactly not what I was looking for (and goes against the grain of how vim's searchpath is otherwise configured for windows :)  ).

Comment: I don't think I suggested you to abandon your Vim setup. Duplicating it in another location or symlinking it is definitely not the same as "abandoning".

Comment: I was half joking :), but a link isn't as beautiful to me as the first suggestion --- I'd rather keep the vimfiles where it is and only where it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `bash` and other UNIX shells, you can do:

```
$ HOME='/path/to/dir' gvim
```

to temporarily set `$HOME` to a different value.

I admit I'm not familiar at all with the Windows command line, but it might be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can define $HOME just like any other environment variable.
Try adding this to the start of your `.vimrc`.

```
let $HOME="C:\Documents and Settings\username"
```

Comment: I tried this, but while vimrc is the first file to be executed by then it is too late to change the value of `$HOME` used by vim for the other initialization files.

Comment: @Ein Oh, ok. Could you maybe try `vim --cmd 'let $HOME = "C:\Documents and Settings\username"'`?

Comment: This doesn't work.  It will set `$HOME`, but not before initialization.  (The backslashes also need to be doubled inside the double quotes.)

Comment: @Ein I see. I didn't actually try with backslashes since I'm not using Vim on Windows, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when running Cygwin (which is similar to MSYS).

The easiest solution for me was to simply set the `HOME` environment variable to an **empty string**. Otherwise, the Cygwin `HOME` value would be appended to the Windows `USERPROFILE` in GVim and it would fail to start correctly.  Not explicitly setting the full path of the `HOME` means that I can use the same start-up files on different systems where the `USERNAME` may not be the same.

Likewise, the `SHELL` environment variable should not be inherited from Cygwin Bash. This results in errors when running `shell` or external programs via `!`. Again, I set this to be an empty variable since Vim is smart enough to figure out what it should be.

In my `.bashrc`, I set the following alias for running Windows `gvim` which starts GVim with the `HOME` and `SHELL` variables set to an empty string – just for that command.

```
gvim="/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Vim/vim74/gvim"
if [ -x "$gvim" ]; then
  alias gvim="HOME= SHELL= \"$gvim\""
fi
unset gvim
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by making a windows symbol link (Win 7 or higher).

Via a symbol link, you can even make `vim` and `gvim` to use the same configuration and plugin.